# Google Play Game Service - Unlocked Achievement Popup not shown for multiple Activities

Tags: android, google-play-games

The first, sorry for my English. I connect google in my main activity, if I unlock a achievement after connect the achievement popup shown. But my problem is, if i play a game, i destroy this activity and never more my achievement popup shown. I complete the unlock without problem, but not shown, How i can force the popup?

I can unlock the achievement by 2 ways:

1- Buy the gold medal, if i don't play any game after connect with google, the achievement popup appears, if i play any game i destroy the activity with which i connect.

Edit: I try to use setviewforpopups and not appears.

2- Completing the gold medal playing the level. My achievement never appears.

I need know how to show the popup when i work with multiple activities for all my games.  A simple mode.

LIFE CYCLE:
1-open app, open main activity, auto connect with GoogleApiClient.

2-Buy a medal, achievement unlock, achievement appear.

3-Play a Game, mainActivity destroy, game activity open.

4-end game, (I try show the achievement in game activity, don't show), push button for go main activity, game activity destroy, main activity open.

5-I try send the achievement by bundle, try shown the achievement, don't shown, buy medal, don't shown.

In the whole process, regardless of the achievement is seen or not, the achievement is updated without problems.

Structure of the app:
I have a activity for the menus and activity for the game and end game.
The connection and operations with google are all in a static object named GOOGLE.

Comment: I think you are going at this wrong; you can force it by doing 'Games.Achievements.unlock(api, c.getString(R.string.achievement_id));`. You, however, are probably doing something wrong with how you award it. By adding the boolean "received" you can check if the user has received it, but if you set it to true before you award the achievement you will probably get the issue

Comment: the archivement is unlocked, I have verified that it only fails when the connecting activity is destroyed.

Comment: This is a hard scenario, because to my knowledge there is no way to check if the popup has been shown. but if the achievement is awarded it probably isn't that big a deal that the popup isn't showed

Comment: Is a problem, i tell you in my ask, the archivement Popup dont shown. I want my user can see the popup.

Comment: And again: If the popup isn't showed because the activity is swapped between unlocking and showing, I don't think there is a solution. It shows the popup when it has been unlocked and no other times. I suggest you(if possible) change to Fragment so you can keep the activity long enough for it to show. Alternativly, create your own popup using DialogFragment, Dialog or AlertDialog.

Comment: I edit my post to see if you understand the problem better. Sorry for my english.

Comment: You have located the source of the problem: The achievement when completing a level. What happens between completing and awarding? Do you change the activity right after? Maybe add a timeout to make sure it waits long enough for the popup to show up.

Comment: And besides, this is impossible without any kind of description of the framework you have.

Comment: ok i put for you a life cycle.

Comment: And the problem isn't to completing a level. The problem have located when i destroy the activity i used for connect. I read other issues in stackoverflow, but all solutions are outdated.

Comment: A better approach to it is to request an update through a bounty or add a comment. It will bring attention to it, though bounties may be more efficient. And now, why do you destroy the Activity that has the Google PLay Games instance? Alternatively you can add a new class and pass the instance to all Activities. And I think a FragmentActivity with Fragments will be the best way to go. Why? Because the FragmentActivity switches the content view while keeping all of the common game-related things. Something to keep in mind is that you should keep track of what Fragment is active and pass

Comment: TouchEvents to the active fragment. But another way to go about it is(assuming you have a menu or win-screen of some kind) is to show the achievement there. But if you want to show instantly when it is won, a FragmentActivity is the way to go, or a delay between win and destroying the Activity.

Comment: in a few days i try FragmentActivity, now i'm working in other code now, txs :)